# C++ / Unkillable process / Can't debug

Tags: c++, debugging, process, kill

I've created a small parser that generates an internal representation of an expression from a string. It does compile correctly, but i just can't debug it. When i try to run it, whether it's in debug mode or not, the console pops-up and immediatly closes. In my process list, the program still appears, using 0% cpu and 100 Ko memory, and there is just no way to kill it except by restarting my PC.

The first time i tred using code blocks with the mingw compiler, and the second time i tried using visual studio 2012, but in both case i got the same problem. When trying to run it with VS it showed an error message saying something like "abort has been called".

I can provide the source code if really needed. I'm not using anything extraordinary in it, just pure standard C++ language and iosream to display results and errors in a console.

What can this be due ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is there recursion taking place, or is there user input expected?

Comment: No user input expected. And yes there is recursion as i am creating trees, but it crashes before i even do the parsing. I've put a breakpoint at the beginning of the program, and it crashes too.

Comment: Would you show the line(s) of code where the **crash** occurs? And perhaps the screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Well, i think i found the problem. When the error pop-up shows up, it also triggers a message from my anti virus that asks me if i want to continue running the program. I chose to continue running it, and i could start debugging. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Antivirus strikes again! Do I hate AV software or what? Sorry, not helping, I know... ;)